# Passing data from a fragment to tabs in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a single activity app, and I want to pass an integer and a string from my app's menu fragment to two tabs. Both tabs must have access to this data. I have used Safe Args to pass this same data from the menu fragment to other fragments that do not contain tabs, but I am stumped on how to pass this same data to the tab fragments.

Comment: This answer might be useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38887547/3973217

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewModel to share data between fragment.

```
class SharedViewModel() : ViewModel(){
    val sharedString = "some string"
}
```

on fragment1:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {
  private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    Log.e(TAG, viewModel.sharedString) // some String 
    ............
```

on fragment2:

```
class Fragment2 : Fragment() {
  private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    Log.e(TAG, viewModel.sharedString) // some String 

    ............
```

P.S : make sure you the viewModel have same instance on both fragment, you can learn more on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)